# MDS-CS in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, mds-cs

When I run my simulator I obtain an error that java 1.6 cannot found for launching MDS-CS 
Can any one help me ? What should I add to run MDS-CS?

Comment: did you add your java home directory to the "Environment Variables" ?

Comment: Did you mean this C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin in Path ?

Comment: no try C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin in PATH 
and    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7\bin in JAVA_PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open command prompt and type java. If you get "java not recognized as an internal or external command" , you havent set the path. MDS-CS needs JDK path to be set. So as Farid farhat told you,set the path in environment variables to point to bin folder in JDK.